# Keyboard/touchpad does not work Surfacebook

Tags: keyboard, kernel

Installed Loki on my surface book but when I reboot the keyboard does not work. The backlight comes on if I touch a key but I don't see anything. Should i install an Ubuntu kernel that has some patches or should I recompile current kernel myself? Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

**There isn't a complete solution right now. If you continue with the following you won't be able to use a external screen and also you'll have some security bugs in your system.**

---

Since you mentioned it earlier that updating to the current mainline kernel (4.8) didn't solve your issues you need to install a custom kernel.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tigerite/kernel
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install linux-surface
```

That commands are going to add a PPA, update your system and install the stable kernel from that PPA.
Then you have to reboot and it's done!

---

https://launchpad.net/~tigerite/+archive/ubuntu/kernel

Comment: So did this and still when I reboot the keyboard and mouse does not work on the surface book. USB keyboard works fine.

Comment: Okay. It seems you need a special kernel version. I've found this > https://launchpad.net/~tigerite/+archive/ubuntu/kernel  however I don't have time right now to explain how to install it. 
Also theres a subreddit https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/ that may help you better than me.

If you have any question you can ask, later at night i'll update my question with the correct answer.

Comment: Updated, let's see if this works!

Comment: So did what you posted. Rebooted logged in the my desktop froze. Had to hold power button to turn off. If I disconnect external display boot up its all fine. But as soon as I plug external display it breaks

Comment: Hmm in that PPA they recommend to add another PPA to update your graphics drivers. In the past I didn't have good experiences with this graphics PPA but you can try to use it. Worst case scenario you'll have to reinstall elementaryOS. I recommend you to backup your files in case you get a black screen next boot.   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers ` and `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: So tried and still a no go for dual monitor.

Comment: It seems that's a bug and it's solved on kernel 4.4.31 but the kernel you are using is 4.4.0  Right now you don't have many options. You can choose what do you want to be broken. If you didn't delete it you probably still have the other kernel I've told you previously (4.8) so you can switch between the two.

To solve your bugs (while using kernel 4.8) you should post it on the kernel bug tracker , but if you don't know how to do it I think you'll better be waiting for somebody to do it or ask for help in any other place.

Comment: Lastly, if you want to remove any of those PPAs do `sudo ppa-purge ppa:blabla/bla `

Comment: Need to update it but here it is. https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/404532

Comment: That's not the place to post such bugs. The correct one is https://bugzilla.kernel.org/  however, you need to post it to the correct place or it won't be fixed (there are thousands of new bugs everyday)

Comment: Why would I post that there? You think this is a kernel issue?

Comment: This is an issue with a kernel driver or xorg. I'm not sure where is the xorg bug tracker but if that's a driver error the kernel is the correct place. Anyway you are better off asking on that subreddit I've mentioned earlier.